# How to create a delay before each print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, delay, text-based

Hi so I'm creating a text-based game with Python and I want to make it so that before each print statement there is a one second delay.

My current solution is to do this:

```
time.sleep(1)
name = input('Do you happen to remember what your name was? ').capitalize()
print(name + ", that's a nice name.")
time.sleep(1)
print("Well it seems that you are all better now so I'm going to have to let you go")
```

However, it is annoying to put a `time.sleep` before each print!

So I'm wondering if anyone knows a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use function to do it?

```
def dprint(s, delay=1):
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(s)
```

Is it ok for you?

```
dprint("hello")
```

Comment: as an improvement we can make `delay` parameter with `1` as default argument

Comment: @AzatIbrakov yes, I see he said one second explicitly.

Comment: @BobBob pleasure, you can accept the solution if helpful. :p

Answer (score 1):

You could patch the print() function using [mock.patch()](https://kite.com/python/docs/mock.patch) like this if you need this functionality to be temporary but for all print() function subcalls:

```
import time
from unittest import mock

OLD_PRINT = print

def make_delayed_print(delay):

    def delayed_print(*args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(delay)
        OLD_PRINT(*args, **kwargs)

    return delayed_print


with mock.patch('builtins.print', make_delayed_print(1)):
    print(1)
    print(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, which will support all existing calls to `print()` without changing the name of the function being called to something else and it supports multiple arguments and keyword arguments (just like the regular `print()` function does):

```
import time

DELAY = 1
regular_print = print  # Save built-in function.

def print(*args, **kwarg):
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    regular_print(*args, **kwarg)
```